# Any danger of using reuse_variables() in v1.0+?

Tags: tensorflow

In the documentation about upgrading to TF 1.0 [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration), there's the following ominous sounding statement:

*Constructions like `tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()` will likely not work. We recommend deleting those lines and replacing them with lines such as the following:*

```
with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=True):
```

I would much prefer sticking with `.reuse_variables()` as the way my code is currently set up makes it rather difficult to use the suggested idiom. So far my code seems to work fine with v1.0, so I'm not sure if it's something I need to worry about or not. The documentation doesn't make it clear if there are plans for deprecation, or what exactly is the problem with using `.reuse_variables()`.

Answer (score 0):

tf.variable_scope is deprecated, so eventually it will stop working. The warning is referring mainly to the capabilities of the TensorFlow 1.0 upgrade script.

Comment: If `tf.variable_scope` is deprecated, why do the instructions suggest using it then? Their suggestion is to switch to `with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=True)`, so it appears that the problem is specific to `.reuse_variables()` and not `tf.variable_scope`